# curlicue letters with mathptmx package

Tags: amsmath, math-fonts, amsfonts, mathptmx

How to show letters like [image] with `mathptmx` package?

I'm using `pdfLaTeX` with `mathptmx` package becasue its gooding looking normal math font letters a-z, A-Z. However, if only with this package, `\mathsrc{...}` is reported as "undefiend sequence" and `\mathcal{...}` is curlicue style like the following:

`\mathcal{F}` shows [image: \mathcal{F}]. If I add `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`, `\mathcal{F}` and `\mathscr{F}` are the same as [image: \mathcal{F}].

What I expect is `\mathcal{F}` shows [image] and `\mathscr{F}` show the one in previous line.

What should I adjust? I hope `mathptmx` package is still being used.

Minimal code script goes like that:

```
% using PdfLaTeX
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$$\mathcal{F}$$
$$\mathscr{F}$$
they are the same
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is the bug in `mathptmx`, hence it uses both `mathcal` and `mathscr` fonts are same, I have modified few of your tags to meet the requirement:

```
% using PdfLaTeX
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cal}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cal}{m}{n}{<->cmsy10}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{rcal}{U}{cal}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{rcal}

\begin{document}
$$\mathcal{F}$$
$$\mathscr{F}$$
they are the same
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

PS: `mathptmx` is the older one, and doesn't have any latest updations...Better switch to `txfonts` packages...

Comment: You can just say `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`. One declaration instead of four.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well. Also lots of thanks for egreg's reminder.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your suggestion, it was really nice. Shall I update my answer?